# angular universal only opening with /index.html

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular7

I have implemented [ssr](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and it has no errors, the thing is after adding angular universal the app wont load unless i add `/index.html` to the URL. then every thing works and all routs are working fine! meaning:

```
http://localhost:4000/
```

keeps loading and does not success, but

```
http://localhost:4000/index.html
```

does. and then redirects to `http://localhost:4000/` ! but if i manually enter a URL in browser or try to open home page without `/index.html` it keeps loading forever

Comment: This seems like an issue with your server config, not Angular.

Comment: I agree with @LazarLjubenović Can you post your web server config here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a classic one

moving to angular universal always remember you can not use, as said [here](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/angular-server-side-rendering-in-node-with-express-universal-engine-dce21933ddce)

> window, document… and other browser objects and their methods (like setTimeout)
>
> all DOM APIs
>
> all other browser-specific APIs like localStorage, IndexedDB…

the problem is that in most cases you are not going to face any error or warning for that!

and the best solution would be to check the platform and then use these where you have to, as below

```
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorage {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) protected platformId: Object) {}

  setItem(key: string, value: any) {

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {

      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));

    }

  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had SetInterval in one of my child component, of main component of Landing page, removing that setInterval solved my issue.

Comment: Yeah, this was my case too. I added `isPlatformBrowser` around it and it fixed my problem.